# What is the best way to pass data to another form using express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an initial form (Form1) which has a Facebook login button. The user fills Form1 and clicks the Facebook login button. After the user authenticates, it is redirected to a second form (Form2) in which some of the fields are automatically filled with the user's Facebook profile information. Form2 has also a submit button.

How can I pass the information in Form1 to Form2 and then send all the information to the server in a single POST through Form2?

Use case: I want the user to first fill some information about something he is interested in in Form1, and then make him fill the least possible amount of personal information in Form2 using some of his Facebook data. I am also interested in sending more information about the user like activities, groups, likes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-page forms can be implemented in the following ways:

- Store the previous form information inside a user session on the server, and then read all the information on the last post
- Render the previous form contents as hidden inputs in the next form and submit all of the information together
- Store all of the information client-side (single page app or possibly backed by a local database) and submit using XHR

I think the more conventional option is using sessions to store the information. A combination of the second and third can be used for a stateless implementation that works with and without JavaScript.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks in using user sessions?

Comment: Well some people don't use sessions at all. Single page apps on RESTful APIs fit this category and they are easier to scale without this server side state. So the drawback is that session information has to be persisted on the server side. For many web apps sessions are normal and are used throughout the app. You just have to be careful about how you manage the state or it can get messy.